# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Error - Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've tried various solutions that are intuitive and then have tried the solutions that have apparently helped others.  I've spun up and terminated my Rails 4 app about 10 times.  So...I thought I'd turn here to see if anyone knew an answer.

Here is the log file:

```
[ 2015-03-06 06:12:27.0070 2619/7fa0f6d60740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: 
Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'webapp', 'cleanup_pidfiles' => 
'L3RtcC9wYXNzZW5nZX*********************yL3RlbXBfZGlyX3RvdWNoZXIucGlk', 
'default_group' => 'webapp', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => 
'/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'webapp', 'log_level' => 
'0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/tmp/passenger-
standalone.1fcb7jr/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 
'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'prestart_urls' => 'aHR0cDovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODAA', 
'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 
'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 
'user_switching' => 'false', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 
'web_server_pid' => '2618', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 
'web_server_worker_gid' => '496', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '497' }
[ 2015-03-06 06:12:27.3877 2622/7fac802f6740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650]:
PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at  
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2618/generation-0/request
[ 2015-03-06 06:12:28.2222 2630/7fe1e0b67740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 
]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at 
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2618/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-03-06 06:12:28.2223 2619/7fa0f6d60740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: 
All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2015/03/06 06:12:29 [error] 2638#0: *3 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is 
not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _,
request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
2015/03/06 06:13:35 [error] 2638#0: *7 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is 
not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.3*.**.***, server: _, 
request:   "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "****************-env.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

I have gem 'passenger' in my gem file...I have tried in both development (because I've seen a number of errors with production and passenger) and production and I swear I have never had this kind of trouble uploading to elastic beanstalk.  In fact this is a very stripped down app with only a static page and both devise for a user and devise for active admin.  No errors or problem in either environment on my local machine.

I've never even realized I needed the index.html file...I always assumed that was only in php and other languages and that Rails took care of that for you with root.  And like I said I've never seen this problem before.  So to test that I put in an index.html file in the public folder and I could see that ahead of my root route on my local machine, but still no dice in AWS.  I'd prefer to be able to drop this in and one of the other configs like just Puma.  And I see a Puma and Nginx config available, but not in the GUI which is what I was planning to just "drop" this in and be done with it for the time being.  I'm using a t2.small instance.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

UPDATE: I've now tried this pushing through Git using Puma...etc.  Trouble everywhere.  It makes no sense.  I even moved it to a "Hello World" app and still nothing.  I'm about done with AWS.  This is ridiculous.  Nearly worse than an iOS release that has massive problems every year.

Comment: what EB you created? I suspect it is not a Ruby on Rails application

Comment: It was Ruby...on EBS right next to Node etc...I've done it a number of times before albeit it has been a while. Webserver -> Preconfigure -> Ruby to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  After today I have gotten this taken care of and hosted properly.  In case this helps someone out...here were the key takeaways:

1) There is a Puma option if you are using CLI that is obvious.  There is ALSO an option in the GUI, however it reads like a sentence instead of a logical select box.  It DOES exist on the front page underneath the selection of the language to be installed.  If you are getting a Passenger Error and expect to be using Puma, this is something you need to change.

2) I had installed a User model that contained an ActiveAdmin role as well.  ActiveAdmin was pulling the gem from GitHub and I am using a machine with GitHub installed already. This really was the problem...switching to production and onto ElasticBeanstalk I forgot that git wasn't already installed.  After going back through the errors many times, the common error was

```
# :github => 'activeadmin/activeadmin'+ '[' -d /vendor/cache ']'
+ bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.

You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories.

[CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Activity failed.
```

This is located in the eb-activity.log.

So, if this is similar to anything happening to you, you can do as follows:

1) start up your instance with the correct server.

2) if you get an error, look through that activity log mentioned above.  (All the logs for that matter)

3) If the error fails similarly there is NO NEED to delete the instance.  Leave it running.

4) SSH into the server instance that you just created.  Run

```
sudo yum update
```

that is more than likely recommended.  And then run

```
sudo yum install git
```

5) Upload the same exact file and name the version 0.1 and when it's through it should be green if this was your only error.  Click the link and Voila.

Comment: I get the same error as - (Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.) 
I have a relative reference for a gem in gemfile.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

For the git binary problem: It will fail again, if more instances are spinning up. You can avoid that by adding a config under $ROOT/.ebextensions which will be used for any new instance.

```
# Install git in order to be able to bundle gems from git
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```